# Can Python 3.6 Script be turned into tool that will work in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, tools, python-3

I have a Python 3.6 script that I want to turn into a tool for that I can use in ArcMap (10.5). Will that even work or will I strictly have to do it in ArcGIS Pro?

I couldn't seem to find any documentation on this.

Comment: Maybe? You'll need to provide more details about whats inside the script. The vast majority of core Python modules works exactly the same in 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: What happens when you run a test by writing a simple tool using Python script in Python 3 and then add it to an ArcMap toolbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is make sure the Python code is compatible with both versions `2.7.x` and `3.x`.  The [six module](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) has many utilities that help with writing forward and backward compatible code while maintaining best practices (use of iterators, etc).

One thing I am not sure about is whether or not you can use the same `.tbx` file between ArcMap and Pro...I'm assuming you can as long as the underlying Python Script tool code is compatible.  Of course, a [Python Toolbox](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm) would probably be the best solution to work with both.

Comment: OK. That's exactly what I was going to do (make a toolbox). A toolbox is a toolbox whether its opened in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, I guess.